# Convert XML string to List<T> without specifiying Element Root in C#

Tags: c#, xml, generics, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

I need to convert the XML string to List, the method should be generic. I wrote a method but its not performing as expected.

**Scenario: #1**

Model Class:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XML:

```
<EmployeeList
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Employee>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Name>Emma</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmpId>2</EmpId>
        <Name>Watson</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeList>
```

**Scenario: #2**

Model Class:

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XML:

```
<PersonList
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Person>
        <PersonId>1</EmpId>
        <Name>Emma</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <PersonId>2</EmpId>
        <Name>Watson</Name>
    </Person>
</PersonList>
```

I need a generic method to Convert the above said XML's to `List<Employee>` and `List<Person>`.

I used the following code

```
public static T[] ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class {
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(@this.Trim().ToStream(),new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
    return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T[])).Deserialize(reader) as T[];
}
```

But I'm getting `NULL`. Kindly assist me how to handle this.

I refereed lots of code but they are telling to specify the Root element as hard-coded value. But I need a generic method.

The Signature should be

```
public static T[] ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class { }
```

Kindly assist me in this regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default root name is `ArrayOfThing`, not `ThingList`, so you will need to tell the serializer:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("EmployeeList"));
```

However, you'll also need to cache and re-use this to prevent assembly memory leaks (only the most basic constructors automatically cache). A static read-only field on a generic type is a good bet, for example:

```
static class SerializerCache<T> {
   public static readonly XmlSerializer Instance = new XmlSerializer(
       typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "List"));
}
```

then use `SerializerCache<T>.Instance` instead of `new XmlSerializer`

Obviously swap lists and arrays if you like...

Comment: @Mastero everything I have mentioned would happen *inside* your existing `ParseXML` method, so : no change required there - just the last line of `ParseXML` would do `SerializerCache<T>.Instance` instead of `new XmlSerializer(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I derived the answer from [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) - [Convert XML string to List<T> without specifiying Element Root in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871038/convert-xml-string-to-listt-without-specifiying-element-root-in-c-sharp/43871172#43871172), which I was marked as Correct.

```
public static class SerializerCache<T> {
   public static readonly XmlSerializer Instance = new XmlSerializer(
       typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "List"));
}

public static class XMLHelper {

    public static List<T> ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class {

        XmlSerializer serializer = SerializerCache<T>.Instance;
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@this));

        if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(@this) && (serializer != null) && (memStream != null)) {
            return serializer.Deserialize(memStream) as List<T>;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Main Method is looks like

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployeeList(string xml) {
    return xml.ParseXML<Employee>();
}
```